# Php Language Selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

Имеем вот такой селектор, [image]

При клике на флаг, к домену добавляется например #US.
Пример - site.com/index.php#US
Теперь вопрос вот в чем, как менять язык всей страницы, ( либо файл другой сделать, )  , мне интересно просто как делают вот эту подмену языка. Что используют в данной ситуации. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делается просто - в шаблоне текстовые и другие изменяемые моменты находятся в переменных, и по url подгружается/вставлятся нужное содержимое - если в таблицах, то из соотвествующих языковых вариантов, если из файлов - из соотв. файла, или все в одном файле - тогда по условию тоже самое, в части касающейся.

Что-то вроде:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['lang']) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "ru";
  include "ru.lang.php";
}
$url = trim(strip_tags($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
if ($url == "/en") {
$_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
    include "en.lang.php";
}
//и т.д. (проверки, закрытие дыр и вариантов написания и несуществующих страниц и прочая и прочая
```

Ну, а в шаблоне что-то вроде:

```
....
    <title><?=$title?></title>
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta name="description" content="<?=$desc?>"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?=$keywords?>"/>
......
```

Ну, а в подключаемых файлах/файле и базе или еще где прописано что-то вроде:

```
$title = "Супер сайт";
```

А в англ:

```
$title = "Super site";
```

Comment: Имеете ли вы какой нибудь исходник где можно эту реализацию посмотреть.

Comment: Реализация - это уже не ответ на вопрос и не подправка кода. Логику я Вам описал - конечно, нужно предусмотреть грамотный разбор url, с механизмом запросов несуществующих страниц и иных вариантов. Для хранения выбранного языка при переходе по страницам/разделам сайта можно использовать куки или сессионные переменные.